# Scala: Remove the last occurrence of a character

Tags: string, scala, indexing

I am trying to remove the last occurrence of a character in a string. I can get its `index`:

```
str.lastIndexOf(',')
```

I have already tried to use `split` and the `replace` function on the string.

Comment: You can try that : `s.substring(0, s.length -1)` (suppose `s` is a string).

Comment: It is not on the last index. It is in the middle of the text

Comment: How large is the string? Do you care about how efficient it is?

Comment: The string is about 4000 characters

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use `patch`.

```
scala> val s = "s;dfkj;w;erw"
s: String = s;dfkj;w;erw

scala> s.patch(s.lastIndexOf(';'), "", 1)
res6: String = s;dfkj;werw
```

Comment: `indexOf` -> `lastIndexOf`

Answer (score 1):

Curious why Scala doesn't have a `.replaceLast` but there must be a reason...

Reverse the String and use `str.replaceFirst` then reverse again

I doubt this is terrible efficient but it is effective :)

```
scala> "abc.xyz.abc.xyz".reverse.replaceFirst("zyx.", "").reverse
res5: String = abc.xyz.abc
```

As a def it would look like this:

```
def replaceLast(input: String, matchOn: String, replaceWith: String) = {
  input.reverse.replaceFirst(matchOn.reverse, replaceWith.reverse).reverse
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
val input = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
val lastIndexOfU = input.lastIndexOf("u")
val splits = input.splitAt(lastIndexOfU)
val inputWithoutLastU = splits._1 + splits._2.drop(1) // "The quick brown fox jmps over the lazy dog"
```

Comment: Warning - `List#tail` is a partial function - ` List().tail
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: tail of empty list`

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> def removeLast(x: Char, xs: String): String = {
     |   
     |   val accumulator: (Option[Char], String) = (None, "")
     |   
     |   val (_, applied) =  xs.foldRight(accumulator){(e: Char, acc: (Option[Char], String)) =>
     |       val (alreadyReplaced, runningAcc) = acc
     |       alreadyReplaced match {
     |            case some @ Some(_) => (some, e + runningAcc)
     |            case None           => if (e == x) (Some(e), runningAcc) else (None, e + runningAcc)
     |         }
     |   }
     | 
     |   applied
     | }
removeLast: (x: Char, xs: String)String

scala> removeLast('f', "foobarf")
res7: String = foobar

scala> removeLast('f', "foobarfff")
res8: String = foobarff
```

Comment: To downvoter: why? I'm happy to receive criticism of my posted solution.