# Eliminate a char from a list of chars in scala

Tags: string, scala, char, indexof

I have this list of chars in Scala:

```
val a = "(i am(a? list) of(/ chars in  )Scala)".toList
```

I want to find the position of the first ')' and eliminate it from the list. How can I do that?

What I did (but did not work):

```
val position = a.tail.indexOf(')')
a.drop(position)
```

and also tried it with `a.take(position)`. I found out that the methods `drop` and `take` are not good for what I need. I want that the method works as follows:

```
input:  (i am(a? list) of(/ chars in )Scala)
output: (i am(a? list of(/ chars in )Scala)
                     ^
```

Comment: What do you mean by nearest?

Comment: 1) "Nearest" to what and with respect to what metric? 2) What have you tried?

Comment: what i did (but did not work): val position = a.tail.indexOf(')') , then a.drop(position) or a.take(position). I found out that the methods .drop and .take are not good for what I need. I want to return "(i am(a? list of(/ chars in  )Scala)" .

Comment: "nearest" means smallest position in the list of chars

Comment: This will give you a good hint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37946103/9297144. And you can use `indexOf`

Comment: "smallest position in the list" is called "first".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The often overlooked `patch()` will do that.

```
a.patch(a.indexOf(')'), List(), 1)
```

Note that `indexOf()` will give misleading results if the target element is not present.

```
val result = if (a.contains(')') a.patch(a.indexOf(')'), List(), 1)
             else a
```

Answer (score 1):

In defence of `take` and `drop`: these two methods do exactly what you wanted:

```
val str = "(i am(a? list) of(/ chars in )Scala)"
val idx = str.indexOf(')')
println(str.take(idx) + str.drop(idx + 1))
```

There is also `span`, which does both `take` and `drop` simultaneously:

```
val (before, after) = str.splitAt(idx)
println(before + after.tail)
```

Both versions output

```
(i am(a? list of(/ chars in )Scala)
(i am(a? list of(/ chars in )Scala)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the element with a `foldLeft`

First perform a `zipWithIndex` to have the index of each char in your list, then with the foldLeft, if the index matchesthe desired index, just don't add that element to the accumulator:

```
a.zipWithIndex
 .foldLeft(Nil: List[Char])((acc, elem) => if (elem._2 == a.indexOf(')')) acc  else acc:+elem._1)
```

Result of the `a.zipWithIndex`

```
List[(Char, Int)] = List(((,0), (i,1), ( ,2), (a,3), (m,4), ((,5), (a,6), (?,7), ( ,8), (l,9), (i,10), (s,11), (t,12), (),13), ( ,14), (o,15), (f,16), ((,17), (/,18), ( ,19), (c,20), (h,21), (a,22), (r,23), (s,24), ( ,25), (i,26), (n,27), ( ,28), ( ,29), (),30), (S,31), (c,32), (a,33), (l,34), (a,35), (),36))
```

Final result:

```
List[Char] = List((, i,  , a, m, (, a, ?,  , l, i, s, t,  , o, f, (, /,  , c, h, a, r, s,  , i, n,  ,  , ), S, c, a, l, a, ))
```

Final result as a String:

```
String = (i am(a? list of(/ chars in  )Scala)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
a.replaceFirst("\\)","")
```

### In Scala REPL:

```
scala> val a = "(i am(a? list) of(/ chars in  )Scala)"
a: String = (i am(a? list) of(/ chars in  )Scala)


scala> a.replaceFirst("\\)","")
res123: String = (i am(a? list of(/ chars in  )Scala)

scala>
```